# Can't make fullscreen SDL programs

Tags: c++, sdl, windows-8.1

I have a little problem about SDL. When I try to add a fullscreen flag (SDL_FULLSCREEN) at screen creation, the program crashes instantly. Personally, I think the problem is due to the fact that Windows 8.1 forbids the program to put itself on fullscreen.

Is my supposition right and, if it is, how can I fix my problem?

Comment: If the issue is with SDL itself, then you could try using `SDL2`. The old `SDL` hasn't been in development for long and it might be that they choose not to do anything to make fullscreen work in `SDL`. You won't loose anything if you start using `SDL2` instead =)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I found the problem : the program's window resolution was too high for my laptop's screen resolution to be fullscreen :P but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @magqudi You are encouraged to post an answer, even to your own question, on Stack Overflow. It is a way of contributing to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem : since my screen resolution is 1366x768, the computer can't handle a fullscreen 800x800 window. Therefore, the program crashes.

Comment: Please note that unlike CRT monitors, TFT screens often cannot support low screen resolutions - this isn't just a SDL problem, my TFT screens physically wont drive anything less than 1024x768... I just get a "no signal" OSD if i try.